# Animation issues in JQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, fadein

I have a jquery below. The purpose is that when the mouse goes over the element, something fade in and when the mouse leaves it is sliding to the right and vanishes.

There are two problems:
-it works for the first time but thereafter it wont as it seems that the element is disappeared and cannot be displayed anymore
-when i move the mouse in and out of the element very fast, it messes up the page design and move the whole elements. It seems something is happening before the animation finishes. How can I wait until the animation finishes? I added a flag to this purpose but it does not work.

```
var flag=0;
$('#text1').on('mouseenter', function(){
    var newEl=document.getElementById("tempel");
    $(newEl).css("visibility","visible");
    if(flag==0) {
        $(newEl).hide().fadeIn('slow', function() {
            flag=1;
        });
    }

});

$('#text1').on('mouseleave', function(){
    var newEl=document.getElementById("tempel");
    $(newEl).animate({
        opacity:0.0,
        paddingLeft:'+=25',
    },500, function() {
        $(newEl).css("visibility","hidden");
        flag=0;
    });
});
```

and here is the HTML:

```
<div id="container2" class="containers">
    <h3 id="text1">Select...</h3>
    <p id="tempel">Type..</p>
</div>
```

and finally the CSS

```
#tempel {
    color: red;
    margin: 25px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The page design issues you are noticing are probably due to the call that your are making to `.hide()` which is equivalent applying the `display:none` CSS rule to that element.

Please see the update code below, along with working code snippet to demonstrate this solution:

```js
// Chain your enter/exit handlers for cleaner code
$('#text1')
.on('mouseenter', function(){

    $("#tempel") // Use jQuery to select tempel
    .stop() // Stop any prior animation that may be in progress
    .animate({
        opacity:1.0,
        paddingLeft:'0px', // update
    },500);
})
.on('mouseleave', function(){

    $("#tempel") // Use jQuery to select tempel
    .stop() // Stop any prior animation that may be in progress
    .animate({
        opacity:0.0,
        paddingLeft:'25px', // update
    },500);
});
```

```css
#tempel {
    /*  visibility: hidden; Remove this */
    color: red;
    margin: 25px; 
    opacity:0;  /* Add this to match pre-animation state */
    padding-left:25px; /* Add this to match pre-animation state */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container2" class="containers">
    <h3 id="text1">Select...</h3>
    <p id="tempel">Type..</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you but it has two problems: it is not same as fadeIn for mouseenter and also if you move the mouse very quickly on the element, the phrase will gradually move towards right of the screen. Should I use deferred objects to prevent it completely? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the way based on your valuable answer:

```
$('#text1')
.on('mouseenter', function(){
    $('#tempel')
    .css("padding-left","0px") //move back the element to its original position
    .stop()
    .animate({
        opacity: 1.0,
    },500);
})
.on('mouseleave', function(){
    $("#tempel")
    .stop()
    .animate({
        opacity :0.0,
        paddingLeft: '+=25',
    },500);
});
```